# PHP - how to distribute items into two arrays base on values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, shopping-cart

I have this array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Item 1
            [price] => 10
            [weight] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Item 2
            [price] => 100
            [weight] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Item 3
            [price] => 30
            [weight] => 300
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Item 4
            [price] => 20
            [weight] => 500
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => Item 6
            [price] => 40
            [weight] => 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [name] => Item 7
            [price] => 200
            [weight] => 10
        )

)
```

And I want to split it into two, so I get this result,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Item 1
                    [price] => 10
                    [weight] => 200
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Item 3
                    [price] => 30
                    [weight] => 300
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [name] => Item 7
                    [price] => 200
                    [weight] => 10
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Item 4
                    [price] => 20
                    [weight] => 500
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => Item 6
                    [price] => 40
                    [weight] => 10
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Item 2
                    [price] => 100
                    [weight] => 20
                )

        )

)
```

Any ideas?

The tricky of this is that the total price of each package must not be more than 250. while the total weight of each must be as even as possbile (even thought it is impossible). You can see what I mean in this picture,

```
name     weight  price
                          package 1
Item 1   200     10
Item 3   300     30
Item 7   10      200
(total)  510     240

                          package 2    
Item 4   500     20
Item 6   10      40
Item 2   20      100
(total)  530     160
```

So is it possible to **move around** the items between these two packages so that total weights are distributed 'evenly'? It seems that it cannot be achieved without 'moving' them **manually**. I **can't** think of any way to achieve the goal by automatic programme. Can you?

Comment: sounds like a dynamic programming problem

Comment: what do you mean `a dynamic programming problem`?

Comment: have you got it working...?

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array by weight

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {return $a['weight']>$b['weight'];});
```

We init our result tables, with a price and weight counters

```
$sum=Array(
    Array("weight" => 0, "price" => 0, "res" => Array()),
    Array("weight" => 0, "price" => 0, "res" => Array()));
```

Then we loop on array

```
while ($obj=array_pop($array)) {
```

We select the lower result array

```
    $ind=($sum[0]['weight']<$sum[1]['weight']) ? 0 : 1;
```

except if it has reached the max amount

```
    if ($sum[$ind]['price']+$obj['price']>250) {
            $ind=1-$ind;

            ## object will be skipped if it can't fit in the allowed amount
            if ($sum[$ind]['price']+$obj['price']>250) continue;
    }
```

and then we fill it

```
    array_push($sum[$ind]['res'], $obj);
    $sum[$ind]['weight']+=$obj['weight'];
    $sum[$ind]['price']+=$obj['price'];

}

print_r($sum);
```

Result as expected:

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [weight] => 510
             [price] => 240
             [res] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 3
                             [name] => Item 3
                             [price] => 30
                             [weight] => 300
                         )

                     [1] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 1
                             [name] => Item 1
                             [price] => 10
                             [weight] => 200
                         )

                     [2] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 7
                             [name] => Item 7
                             [price] => 200
                             [weight] => 10
                         )

                 )

         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [weight] => 530
             [price] => 160
             [res] => Array
                 (
                     [0] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 4
                             [name] => Item 4
                             [price] => 20
                             [weight] => 500
                         )

                     [1] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 2
                             [name] => Item 2
                             [price] => 100
                             [weight] => 20
                         )

                     [2] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 6
                             [name] => Item 6
                             [price] => 40
                             [weight] => 10
                         )

                 )

         )

 )
```

Comment: Incoming array is sorted, and you take the value from the biggest to the lowest: 500,300,200,30,20,10,10. This line chose the array with the lowest weight...

Comment: thanks Adam for explaining that line. again, why do you use `array_pop`? and why `$ind=1-$ind;`? do you mind explaining them a little bit more please?

Comment: I know that `array_pop` is to remove the last item off an array. but i don't understand how removing the last item off an array works in this solution....

Comment: the array is sorted, so array_pop will get the item with the maximum weight. Getting the maximum weight first, you will be able to have closer weight at the end for both arrays. `$ind=1-$ind` inverts the selected item : 0 becomes 1, 1 becomes 0 in case it worthes too much

Comment: Thanks Adam for this further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It have nothing to do with PHP or arrays. As I understand your question it's kind of [Multiple knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multiple_knapsack_problem). So it's lots of math (see some solution [here](http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter6.pdf)) and maybe easiest way is to programmatically chaeck all possible variants.